# HTTP Client and POST params in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to convert my jQuery code into Angular2. jQuery code works well but Angular2 code gives a different output from API.

I already checked params & endpoint using firebug/console & those are the same. Can somebody suggest something to highlight the issue please?

**jQuery code:**

```
$.post(endpoint, { email_login: username, password_login: password }, function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

**Angular 2 code:**

```
    let url = this.endpoint;
    let body = JSON.stringify({email_login: username, password_login: password});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as any)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let url = this.endpoint;
    let body = JSON.stringify({email_login: username, password_login:password});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

 return this.http.post(url, body, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.handleData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

You can handle server success response in handleData and error response handleError

```
handleData(res: any) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body || { };
}

handleError(error: any) {
    let body = error.json();
    console.log(body);
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for...I am getting a different result as parameters are not being post properly.